# Position image over image on two neighbour divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox, z-index

I want to have a centered box with two images on each side of a box, overlapping. Later, I'll move top image for each box with jquery animate function away from bottom image.

This is my code so far:

```css
html,
body,
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#center {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
#left {
  //border:1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  //position:absolute;

}
#right {
  //border: 1px solid green;
  width: 400px;
  float: right;
  //position:absolute;

}
#top {
  z-index: 1;
}
#under {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="center">
      <div id="left">
        <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/p5mgljj5x/drums_left.jpg" id="top">
        <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/4vp56ei11/workout_left.jpg" id="under">
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <!--<img src="http://s32.postimg.org/6ep4p4dz9/drums_right.jpg" id="under">-->
        <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/mzs5r1fph/workout_right.jpg" id="top">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<footer>
</footer>

</html>
```

I have managed to center this box and add one picture for each side (left, right), but when I want to add another picture on either side, that has z-index: -1 it breaks into new line..

Fiddle that is showing problem: https://jsfiddle.net/bjgydLvo/

Answer (score 3):

You need to give your second image a class and position it absolute.

```
<img class="second" src="http://s32.postimg.org/4vp56ei11/workout_left.jpg" id="under">

.second {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Make sure you position your left element relative too

```
#left {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Remove #under

Working example

https://jsfiddle.net/46pk1vdf/4/

Comment: This actually worked too, but answer from user6028084 is faster. +1 anyway!

Comment: No worries :) Glad i could help

Comment: Actually, I uncommented that second image on right div and everything breaks:D

Answer (score 2):

z-index wont work without assigning position..

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bjgydLvo/2/

```
#under{
   z-index:-1;
   float: none;
   height: auto;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 400px;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: It seems that pictures under are now all under left image.. Right image doesnt have anything beneath it..